# iOS countinous integration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to include continuous integration in my project and I am using azure-pipeline. my `azure-pipeline.yml` file code is as follows

```
trigger:
 - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-10.13'

steps:
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    scheme: 'sade'
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    configuration: 'Release'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcodeproj/sade.xcworkspace'
    xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: 8, 9, 10, default, specifyPath
```

I got the error:

> Error: The Xcode workspace was specified, but it does not exist or is
>   not a directory:
>   /Users/vsts/agent/2.144.0/work/1/s/**/*.xcodeproj/sade.xcworkspace

And if I change `xcWorkspacePath` to `sade.xcworkspace` I get the error:

> Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65

If it could be built successfully on local, please have a try to change the sdk value from **`iphoneos`** to **`iphonesimulator`**. If it still doesn't work for you.

You could set the `system.debug` to true to get more detail error information.

[image]